# how to create edit text control

Tags: android

The current edit text control is not capable of displaying/Rendering Hindi text correcltly , hence I need to develop an edit text from scratch, i have done this in winCE(overridding CEdit), so i have that cpp code, i am new to android can some body please tell me how can i create the edit text(override) in android, i have installed the android SDK's for windows XP and using eclipse as an editor, if requires i have no problems to move to Ubuntu as the development environment.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make any Edit Text for displaying hindi font...

EditText support unicode format.. just make a string hindi unicode and set the text of EditText with the string as simple it is...
I did it for displaying Chinese Font .. It works grt.. You just need to know the Unicode of hindi characters

for e.g

String s = " \u4E01 \u4E02";

EditText t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

t.setText(s);

Comment: thanks for the reply Javanator, yes it will display the hindi text, but its not rendering it properly. Is any one has any idea about how to handle the cursor movements in edittext?